# How to let a user browse for a url in an html form?

Tags: html, forms

I am new to html and webdesign so please excuse any 'stupid' question ...

Similar to the `<input type='file' ...` field is there an easy way to let the user browse for an url of a webpage?

Currently I display a text field where the user has to enter or paste an url.

But it would maybe be nicer if he could browse the web inside a dialog and when hitting [OK] button the current url is copied automatically into the input field.

Is there any/Which way to go?

Comment: Such an input field already exists – it’s called the browser address bar.

Comment: If I understand you, you could (using jquery in this example) make a text input field <input id="url" type="text" />, then: $('#url').val(document.URL);  That will put the current url into the text field.

Comment: @reggie user thanks, but the url I would want to copy is the url from the 'BrowseForUrl' dialog I wanted to display. See my comment in the answer from Jozef Legény what I wanted to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a simple text input field.

Your client is already using a browser and can browse web in it, it is trivial for them to copy and paste the link from the navigation bar. It would severely hinder their experience if they had to use a custom-made browser inside a dialog.

Comment: Yes ... there is maybe no other way to go that makes sense. I just thought not to force the user to open an extra window + copy the address + go back + paste it in the field by hand could make it a better experience for them. Also I did not want to create my own browser - just display google and let them surf for anything, click ok and they are done. Just similar to what they do when they browse for a file they want to upload.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with JavaScript for security issues. But there is a workaround if you must have this feature in your app, you'll need to mix flash and javascript together.

Here is an example of a working copy:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="5" cols="70">
    The David Walsh Blog is the best blog around!  MooTools FTW!
</textarea>
<br /><br />
<p><input type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy to Clipboard" /></p>
```

The above HTML features a form element with the ID "box-content" and a button with the ID "copy". Both of those element IDs will come into play with ZeroClipboard.

**The ZeroClipboard JavaScript**

```
//set path
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://davidwalsh.name/demo/ZeroClipboard.swf');
//create client
var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
//event
clip.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
    clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
});
clip.addEventListener('complete',function(client,text) {
    alert('copied: ' + text);
});
//glue it to the button
clip.glue('copy');
```

Comment: Thanks unixmiah ... but in my case I can not introduce flash into my page. I stick with the copy-paste-text input solution for now.